# How to align the input data in respective Columns?

Tags: winforms, savefiledialog

I am new to C# and trying to learn it somehow. So, may be code look ugly.
Right now I'm developing a windows form application.

I am trying to create a text file where I want to save the input data from multiple Text Boxes in rows and columns.

Text file creation, data saving and data reading is working with the following code, but the data is not aligned according to the respective columns.
`PadRight` method and Indent changing is not working either.

kindly help me with this code to align the data accordingly.

```
`//Reading file through Open button in menustrip
  private void OpenOCtrlOToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|";
            open.FilterIndex = 1;
            open.Title = "Open file";

            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(open.FileName);

                    string[] fileData = File.ReadAllLines(open.FileName);
                    var parts = fileData[4].Split(new string[] { "      " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    ucMainPageOutline.Instance.ProjN.Text = parts[0];
                    ucMainPageOutline.Instance.ProjL.Text = parts[1];
                    ucMainPageOutline.Instance.Ownr.Text = parts[2];
                    ucMainPageOutline.Instance.Dsinr.Text = parts[3];
                    ucMainPageOutline.Instance.Sprvsr.Text = parts[4];
                    ucMainPageOutline.Instance.ConstT.Text = parts[5];
                    ucMainPageOutline.Instance.Bldr.Text = parts[6];
                    ucMainPageOutline.Instance.Sec.Text = parts[7];
                    ucMainPageOutline.Instance.MExcD.Text = parts[8];
                    ucMainPageOutline.Instance.ExcD.Text = parts[9];
                    ucMainPageOutline.Instance.ExcW.Text = parts[10];
                }
                catch(Exception)
                { }
                try
                {
                    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(open.FileName);

                    string[] fileData = File.ReadAllLines(open.FileName);
                    var parts = fileData[12].Split(new string[] { "      " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    ucInputM.Instance.GWLt.Text = parts[0];
                    ucInputM.Instance.WallT.Text = parts[1];
                    ucInputM.Instance.HPSize.Text = parts[2];
                    ucInputM.Instance.WallL.Text = parts[3];
                    ucInputM.Instance.WStifness.Text = parts[4];
                    ucInputM.Instance.ElasticM.Text = parts[5];
                    ucInputM.Instance.Walldia.Text = parts[6];
                    ucInputM.Instance.WallK.Text = parts[7];
                    ucInputM.Instance.Strength.Text = parts[8];
                    ucInputM.Instance.Steel.Text = parts[9];
                    ucInputM.Instance.SprtT.Text = parts[10];
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }

                try
                {
                    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(open.FileName);

                    string[] fileData = File.ReadAllLines(open.FileName);
                    var parts = fileData[18].Split(new string[] { "      " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    ucInputM.Instance.StrutDim.Text = parts[0];
                    ucInputM.Instance.Strut1st.Text = parts[1];
                    ucInputM.Instance.StrutVS.Text = parts[2];
                    ucInputM.Instance.StrutHS.Text = parts[3];
                    ucInputM.Instance.StrutN.Text = parts[4];
                    ucInputM.Instance.StrutStif.Text = parts[5];
                    ucInputM.Instance.StrutL.Text = parts[6];
                    ucInputM.Instance.AnchorLoad.Text = parts[7];
                    ucInputM.Instance.Anchor1st.Text = parts[8];
                    ucInputM.Instance.AnchorAngle.Text = parts[9];
                    ucInputM.Instance.AnchorFL.Text = parts[10];
                    ucInputM.Instance.AnchorLL.Text = parts[11];
                    ucInputM.Instance.AnchorVS.Text = parts[12];
                    ucInputM.Instance.AnchorHS.Text = parts[13];
                    ucInputM.Instance.AnchorNo.Text = parts[14];
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }
            }
        }

        // Saving/Creating file through save button in menustrip
        private void SaveSCtrlSToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

            save.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|";
            save.FilterIndex = 1;
            save.Title = "Save File";

            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string[,] P = new string[1, 11]
                {
                    {ucMainPageOutline.Instance.ProjN.Text, ucMainPageOutline.Instance.ProjL.Text, ucMainPageOutline.Instance.Ownr.Text, ucMainPageOutline.Instance.Dsinr.Text, ucMainPageOutline.Instance.Sprvsr.Text, ucMainPageOutline.Instance.ConstT.Text, ucMainPageOutline.Instance.Bldr.Text, ucMainPageOutline.Instance.Sec.Text, ucMainPageOutline.Instance.MExcD.Text, ucMainPageOutline.Instance.ExcD.Text, ucMainPageOutline.Instance.ExcW.Text}
                };

                string[,] P1 = new string[1, 11]
                {
                    {ucInputM.Instance.GWLt.Text, ucInputM.Instance.WallT.Text, ucInputM.Instance.HPSize.Text, ucInputM.Instance.WallL.Text, ucInputM.Instance.WStifness.Text, ucInputM.Instance.ElasticM.Text, ucInputM.Instance.Walldia.Text, ucInputM.Instance.WallK.Text, ucInputM.Instance.Strength.Text, ucInputM.Instance.Steel.Text, ucInputM.Instance.SprtT.Text}
                };

                string[,] P2 = new string[1, 15]
                {
                    { ucInputM.Instance.StrutDim.Text,ucInputM.Instance.Strut1st.Text, ucInputM.Instance.StrutVS.Text, ucInputM.Instance.StrutHS.Text, ucInputM.Instance.StrutN.Text, ucInputM.Instance.StrutStif.Text, ucInputM.Instance.StrutL.Text, ucInputM.Instance.AnchorLoad.Text, ucInputM.Instance.Anchor1st.Text, ucInputM.Instance.AnchorAngle.Text, ucInputM.Instance.AnchorFL.Text, ucInputM.Instance.AnchorLL.Text, ucInputM.Instance.AnchorVS.Text, ucInputM.Instance.AnchorHS.Text, ucInputM.Instance.AnchorNo.Text }
                };

                using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(save.FileName))
                {

                    write.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------Project Outline information---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    write.WriteLine(" ");
                    write.WriteLine("{0,-15} {1,-15} {2,-15} {3,-15} {4,-15} {5,-15} {6,-15} {7,-15} {8,-15} {9,-15} {10,-15}", "P.Name", "P.Location", "Owner", "Designer", "Supervisor", "C.Time", "Builder", "Section #", "M.E.Depth", "E.Depth", "E.Width");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        write.WriteLine(" ");
                        write.WriteLine("{0,-15} {1,-15} {2,-15} {3,-15} {4,-15} {5,-15} {6,-15} {7,-15} {8,-15} {9,-15} {10,-15}", P[i, 0], P[i, 1], P[i, 2], P[i, 3], P[i, 4], P[i, 5], P[i, 6], P[i, 7], P[i, 8], P[i, 9], P[i, 10]);
                    }

                    write.WriteLine(" ");
                    write.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------Input Module Information---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    write.WriteLine(" ");
                    write.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------Wall Information---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    write.WriteLine(" ");
                    write.WriteLine("{0,-15} {1,-15} {2,-15} {3,-15} {4,-15} {5,-15} {6,-15} {7,-15} {8,-15} {9,-15} {10,-15}", "GWL", "W.Type", "H.P.Size", "W.Length", "W.Stiffness", "W.E.Modulus", "1st.C.Dia", "K.wall", "UCS", "St.Type", "S.Type");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        write.WriteLine(" ");
                        write.WriteLine("{0,-15} {1,-15} {2,-15} {3,-15} {4,-15} {5,-15} {6,-15} {7,-15} {8,-15} {9,-15} {10,-15}", P1[i, 0], P1[i, 1], P1[i, 2], P1[i, 3], P1[i, 4], P1[i, 5], P1[i, 6], P1[i, 7], P1[i, 8], P1[i, 9], P1[i, 10]);
                    }

                    write.WriteLine(" ");
                    write.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------Support Information---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    write.WriteLine(" ");
                    write.WriteLine("{0,-15} {1,-15} {2,-15} {3,-15} {4,-15} {5,-15} {6,-15} {7,-15} {8,-15} {9,-15} {10,-15} {11,-15} {12,-15} {13,-15} {14,-15}", "Strut.Sec", "Strut.1st.L", "Strut.VS", "Strut.HS", "Strut#", "Strut.Stiff", "Strut.L", "D.Load", "Anchor.1st.L", "Anchor.Angle", "Anchor.FF.L", "Anchor.S.L", "Anchor.VS", "Anchor.HS", "Anchor#");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        write.WriteLine(" ");
                        write.WriteLine("{0,-15} {1,-15} {2,-15} {3,-15} {4,-15} {5,-15} {6,-15} {7,-15} {8,-15} {9,-15} {10,-15} {11,-15} {12,-15} {13,-15} {14,-15}", P2[i, 0], P[i, 1], P2[i, 2], P2[i, 3], P2[i, 4], P2[i, 5], P2[i, 6], P2[i, 7], P2[i, 8], P2[i, 9], P2[i, 10], P2[i, 11], P2[i, 12], P2[i, 13], P2[i, 14]);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("File Saved");
                    write.Dispose();
                }`
```

[image]

Comment: Aligning text in a text file doesn't make much sense. The way that you see the text depends to the text editor and font which text editor uses. In general, if you are going to export data to text format, usually exporting in comma separated format is a good option.

Comment: This has to make sense because the end user would be able to make changes and read the file back to the respective columns. Also in a comma separated file, it is not clear that which value belongs to which input parameters, so user cannot edit the text file accordingly.

Comment: `.csv` files can be edited by excel as well as any text editor.

Comment: Using a monospaced font like `Courier New` or `Lucida Console` you can see different result in notepad. That's why I say aligning text in a text file doesn't make much sense.

Comment: But changing font doesn't affect the alignment. I don't understand with the same -15 indent value, why the lines are not aligned.

Answer (score 0):

This alignment problem in text file is very irritating. So, I quit saving data in text file and moved to the excel file. now I have no problem regarding alignment of the text. there are some formatting issues regarding excel but those are of minor importance.